# Determine if path is valid javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a path which is passed down to me as a javascript variable, which will reference to an image (maybe).
`../app/assets/icon.png`. In the case that the path is invalid or doesn't exist, I want to use a different file, located somewhere else. In the end, it should look something like this:

```
var verifiedPath = existsAndIsValid(path) ? path : '../app/default/icon.png'
```

Is there a simple one-liner in which I can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The very simple [exists](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) function is deprecated and recommends using [stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) or [access](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_access_path_mode_callback) instead. They are all core NodeJS.

```
fs.access('path', fs.R_OK, (err) => {
  if (!err) { console.log("File exists");
});
```